# Malformed URL Port. How to rewrite or redirect?

Tags: apache, http, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, jetty

I have a malformed URL:

```
http://myserver.com:8080xyz/abc
```

As you can see the port is incorrectly concatenated with a string.

- Would any webserver be able to receive this request?
- Is it possible for the server to handle this URLs by re-directing / forwarding / rewriting to a well formed URL?

I'm currently using Jetty as my webserver, but I'm open to placing an Apache server in front of it if mod_rewrite can help with this task.

It might seem like a weird question, but some context might clarify why I am asking this: my team submitted an iOS application to the Apple store, and one important URL slipped by with this problem. If we re-upload our binary we will miss a hard deadline, so I'm trying to look for options in our server to handle the malformed URL at least until a new version is approved.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A malformed URL cannot be handled with a web server or operating system.